# How to use Postgresql GIN index with ARRAY keyword

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

I'd like to create `GIN` index on a scalar text column using an `ARRAY[]` expression like so:

```
CREATE TABLE mytab (
 scalar_column TEXT
)

CREATE INDEX idx_gin ON mytab USING GIN(ARRAY[scalar_column]);
```

Postgres reports an error on `ARRAY` keyword.

I'll use this index later in a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM mytab WHERE ARRAY[scalar_column] <@ ARRAY['some', 'other', 'values'];
```

How do I create such an index?

Comment: Are you just trying to check if the value of `scalar_column` matches one of a list of values? If so, you can just use a regular btree index and filter `WHERE scalar_column IN ('some', 'other', 'values')`

Comment: Which index should I use in this case?

Comment: As a workaround I've done this

`CREATE INDEX idx_gin ON mytab USING GIN(string_to_array(scalar_column, ''));`

I wonder if there is a proper way to create such an index.

Comment: The index and your query don't make any sense to begin with. Why do you think you need an index on an array expression?

Comment: I think that `<@` operator with GIN index is faster than `= ANY` operator with no index. How would you speed up queries which check value against a given array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add an extra pair of parentheses that is necessary for syntactical reasons:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gin ON mytab USING gin ((ARRAY[scalar_column]));
```

The index does not make a lot of sense. If you need to search for membership in a given array, use a regular B-tree  index with `= ANY`.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please be so kind to elaborate on usefulness of this index. I'd like to speed up queries which check if scalar value is in a given array.

Comment: I have elaborated.