# Postgres index type for array column for ANY queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a Postgres table with a column that's an array of strings. The only searches that will be done using this column will be either `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` and queries asking for rows where the array contains some value (e.g., `'vote'=ANY(T.column)`).

Now, I know that a GIN index supports the `<@` operator which checks if the elements of one array are included in the other (of which `ANY` is really the special case of a 1 element array). However, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030313/how-to-use-postgresql-gin-index-with-array-keyword) seems to suggest that `ANY` works fine with B-tree indexes as does Shana K's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value) (well actually she suggests `<@` works with them).

However, the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/indexes-types.html) seem to only mention `<`, `=`, `<=` etc. as supported by B-tree. What index do I need to support a query searching for rows where an array column contains a specified value?

**EDIT:** Since posting both of those answers have now been updated to no longer suggest that a B-tree index will work.

Comment: Create the index, then check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) and you will know if the index is used.

Comment: Postgres is smart enough that for small databases it uses a full scan so when I do EXPLAIN on my small test database it just tells me it is going to do a full scan.  I'd need to populate a large database to determine this so seems easier and more reliable to ask what the best option is.

Comment: To help using ANY (array contains) ,  you'd better :
create index <index_name> on <table_name> using GIN (<column> gin__int_ops)
To evaluate the usage,  it's not hard to prepopulate enough data in the target table for a test.

Comment: I presume that gin__int_ops is only helpful if my arrays are null free arrays of integers (in this case they are actually arrays of strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed explanation why the `ANY` construct **with the indexed column to the right** cannot tap into a GIN index (or any index, for that matter):

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

But [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) can. See:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

To force a test with a small table, you can disable (massively discourage, really) sequential scans in your current session with:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

See:

- [Postgres query optimization (forcing an index scan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554302/postgres-query-optimization-forcing-an-index-scan/14555618#14555618)